# LWC Quick Action Error with Record EDIT Form for Lookup Field after Summer 22 Update

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, summer-22

We have an LWC for quick Action which creates a Quote it is displayed on Opportunity Layout.

It has a Record Edit Form which has some Fields and it displays the values, the Field **Payment Terms** is a Look up.

[image]

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-stacked" field-name="Payment_Terms__c" required> 
    </lightning-input-field>
</div>
```

Now after Summer it started showing exception **"Select an Option from the Pick List or Remove the Search term."**

When we tried to debug it is showing following exception in Console, Can anyone please guide or assist what has gone wrong with Summer 22. This was working perfectly in Production.

[image]

Comment: I recommend raising a support case with Salesforce. This isn't the only problem with Summer 22 prerelease.

Comment: @Dumb Code The patch fix has been rolled out across all instances. Please check

Answer (score 1):

We have an ongoing investigation for this behavior numbered #W-11115198 logged with the concerned salesforce product team. It was reported by several other customers too and is being worked on with top priority.

I will update this thread as I have more details.

Known issue link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002aLwoQAE

Comment: Thanks @swetha!! Please keep the community updated!!