# Salesforce lwc *&exception .Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ma')

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, aura, summer-22

I use aura, replacing the standard create button like this(CreateAccountCompt):

```
<aura:component description="CreateAccountCompt"
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:actionOverride"
                access="global">
    <div>
        <c:createAccount></c:createAccount>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

c:createAccount

c:createAccount is a lightning web component

like this :

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
            id="recor222313dCreateForm1234123"
            object-api-name="Account">
        <!--国家-->
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Country__c"></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Country__c is a lookup field.
When I can't search for "United States", click "Show All Results for 'United States' ", and the error will be generated.
The stack of javascript looks like this:

```
    aura_prod.js:887 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ma')
    at Object.dispatchGlobalEvent (aura_prod.js:887:85)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:708)
    at Object.n.getAura (auraUtils.js:1:389)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:694)
    at eval (platformOverlayUtils.js:1:4392)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new b (aura_prod.js:994:269)
    at Object.o.showCustomOverlay (platformOverlayUtils.js:1:4340)
    at eval (deprecatedOverlayUtils.js:1:668)
```

[image]
[image]

When I try other objects and other lookup fields, the same error will be reported.
The current version is Summer '22 Patch 4.5, the previous version Spring '22 Patch 19.9 will not have this problem

Comment: The GACK -1895801639 points to error: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading Q)] in salesforce logs which is related to on going Inv  #W-11115198  as pointed in [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/375961/80089)

Comment: Where can I see the progress of this case #W-11115198

Comment: Summer 22 is about to be updated in June. I'm worried about the production environment. Can you tell me?

Comment: This is an internal Inv with the Salesforce R&D team so you can't see it. I'll let you know soon as we have known issue  link created for this

Comment: Known issue link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002aLwoQAE

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I would like to know when it will be fixed or if there is a solution

Comment: As mentioned in the KI, the bug fix is in progress in this weeks Summer '22 patch 5.0. Please check your org's instance to verify in the KI if the fix has been applied. Thank you

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, we will follow it next week

Comment: My sandbox instance is in CS72, at trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002aLwoQAE, it has been described to be fixed, but the test found that it is not work, and I found that the stack is different, please help to see if it is the same problem.

Comment: I've checked with the concerned team. The patch fix starts today and should be complete by Friday. Let's wait and check back.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply, looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: In version Summer '22 Patch 5.1, this problem does not occur, thanks for the previous communication